# Active record query using joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-record-query

I have three different models User, Order, Product:-

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :products
end
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :orders
end
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product 
end
```

How to find all the products which an user has ordered using a one line active-record query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained [in the ActiveRecord documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables):

```
Product.joins(:orders).where(orders: { user_id: user.id })
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried that already and got following error:-    **ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection: SELECT `product`.* FROM `product` INNER JOIN `order` ON `order`.`product_id` = `product`.`productid` WHERE `orders`.`user_id` = 5**

Comment: You have some error somewhere in the table definition. `Product` should trigger a query on the table `products`, not `product`. Moreover, `productid` is not a valid id, it should be `id`. Did you make some customizations? They are the reason why your query doesn't work.

Comment: I did make some customization. Primary key of my product table is productid instead of id.

Comment: Also all my table names are singular i.e **user,product & order**

Answer (score 3):

Another options here is using [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relation:

Add to `User` model

```
has_many :products, through: :orders
```

and now `user.products` does the trick

Comment: I can't do that as users already have many products as each product is posted by a user

Comment: When I answered your users did not have products relation :) If so, I would recommend to setup two relations like `has_many :posted_product, class_name: "Product"` and `has_many :ordered_products, through: :orders, class_name: "Product"`. Take a look on association options like *through*, *class_name*, *foreign_key*

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work mostly because of some customizations I made on the table.

Comment: I would recommend to rewrite db schema according to Rails conventions - it seems to be less pain to do now than in future. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I got it finally through this

```
 Product.joins(:orders).where(order: { user_id: user.id })
```